# Send dictionary data via HTTP POST method in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, httprequest

I'm trying to make an HTTP post request with params set in a dictionary here's my dict

```
let parameters    = [
                    ["name": "tag","value": "login"],
                    ["name": "email","value": "s@s.com"],
                    ["name": "password","value": "aaaa"]
                    ]
```

but I don't to know how to access it in hers's my complete request function

```
    func data_request(_ url:String)
{
    let parameter = [
                    ["name": "tag","value": "login"],
                    ["name": "email","value": "s@s.com"],
                    ["name": "password","value": "aaaa"]
                    ]
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let paramString = parameter?
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        {
            print(dataString)
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: What's the error? Also, try to add the sending parameter JSON Structure.

Comment: error is I don't know how to set http body

Comment: let paramString = parameter? at this line

Comment: Actually making param is depend on your backend structure, try to tell us what param need to prepare so that we can help you!

Comment: I am sending these params for authentication from server.just to check that user is existed or not.that are for my sign in view

Comment: Is it right structure of preparing params, they need an array?

Comment: I don't know.i am new to iOS so I thought its the best way to send it in a dictionary.if u have another way..I would appreciate it:)

Comment: First of that is not a dictionary it an array. and second, ask your backend developer what's the structure for a parameter.

Comment: You need to clarify: Is `print("error")` called? Is `print(dataString)`? Shouldn't you use `request.httpBody  = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options:[])` instead? Avoid Foundation Stuff like `NSString`, `NSMutableURLRequest`, etc. on Swift 3, prefers the Swift 3 version: `URLRequest`, `String`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Need to convert dictionary to json string like below:

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

After that pass to the http.Body

// insert json data to the request

 request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

 request.HTTPBody = jsonData

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                print("Result -> \(result)")

            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        return task



    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `Dictionary` into `Data` and set it to `httpBody`
you could solve in this way

`let paramData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: [])
request.httpBody = paramData`